# Multiple click handlers for a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I've written a few events to handle opening and closing of a snap js drawer. This code below works, but I feel it could be written more efficiently. Any suggestions?

```
function openMobileMenu() {
    event.preventDefault();
    snapper.open('left');
    $('#btn-menu').off('click', openMobileMenu);
    $('#btn-menu').on('click', closeMobileMenu);
}

function closeMobileMenu() {
    event.preventDefault();
    snapper.close('left');
    $('#btn-menu').on('click', openMobileMenu);
    $('#btn-menu').off('click', closeMobileMenu);
}

$('#btn-menu').on('click', openMobileMenu);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your code modular and your concepts explicit.

You can start by creating a `MobileMenu` object which encapsulates the logic.

*Note: The following code was not tested.*

```
var MobileMenu = {
    _snapper: null,
    _$button: null,
    _direction: 'left',
    init: function (button, snapper, direction) {
        this._$button = $(button);
        this._snapper = snapper;
        if (direction) this._direction = direction;

        this._toggleSnapperVisibilityWhenButtonClicked();
    },
    _toggleSnapperVisibilityWhenbuttonClicked: function () {
        this._$button.click($.proxy(this.toggle, this));
    },
    toggle: function () {
        var snapperClosed = this._snapper.state().state == 'closed',
            operation = snapperClosed? 'open' : 'closed';

        this._snapper[operation](this._direction);
    }
};
```

Then in your page you can just do the following to initialize your feature:

```
var mobileMenu = Object.create(MobileMenu).init('#btn-menu', snapper);
```

Modularizing your code will make it more maintainable and understandable in the long run, but also allow you to unit test it. You also gain a lot more flexibily because of the exposed API of your component which allows other code to interact with it.

E.g. you can now toggle the menu visibility with `mobileMenu.toggle()`.

Comment: I really like what you've done here. Two questions though. 1) Why use an underscore for variable declarations? 2) I'm calling my current script from a scripts.js How do I implement MobileMenu object with that setup.

Comment: @certainstrings 1) The `_` in front of variable names is a popular naming convention to identify that these should be private members and shouldn't be accessed or modified from outside. 2) You can either put it in it's own file (e.g. `mobile-menu.js`) and include it in your page. If you end up with many scripts you can use a compiler such as Google Closure to generate a single minimized file out of your multiple script files automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was a naming convention, just wasn't familiar with ref to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to keep track of the state:

```
var menu_open = false;
$("#btn-menu").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (menu_open) {
        snapper.close('left');
    } else {
        snapper.open('left');
    }
    menu_open = !menu_open; // toggle variable
});
```

Answer (score 1):

snap has a `.state()` method, which returns an object stuffed with properties, one of which is `.state`.

I think you want :

```
$('#btn-menu').on('click', function() {
    if(snapper.state().state == "closed") {
        snapper.open('left');
    } else {
        snapper.close('left');
    }
});
```

Or, in one line :

```
$('#btn-menu').on('click', function() {
    snapper[['close','open'][+(snapper.state().state == 'closed')]]('left');
});
```

Also, check [How do I make a toggle button?](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/#--how-do-i-make-a-toggle-button) in the documentation.

Comment: I stole your `snapper.state()`, hope you dont mind... ;)

Comment: It isn't mine - free to use by encapsulators everyhwere :/

Comment: This is cleaner than what I wrote and it works. Didn't realize there was a .state method. Read the manual I suppose.